# Android Kotlin open Link with button

Tags: android, kotlin

i try to open an link with a button in Kotlin, but if i use this code

```
fun openNewTabWindow(urls: String, context: Context) { 
    val uris = Uri.parse(urls) 
    val intents = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris) 
    val b = Bundle() 
    b.putBoolean("new_window", true) 
    intents.putExtras(b)
    context.startActivity(intents)
}
```

And in my button i use

```
openNewTabWindows("https://Google.com/")
```

It say it need context After url?

What does that mean?

Comment: After reformatting your code it is evident that you need a `context` which is typically `Activity` in this case.

Comment: Ok, so openNewTabWindows("https://Google.com/", Activity) ?

Comment: Well since your method signature has 2 variables you need to pass them both

Comment: If you call this from un activity then yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks i try it tomorrow

Comment: It is probably ("Google.com/", this) since you are inside the activity and this refers to the current instance

Answer (score 3):

`openNewTabWindow(urls: String, context: Context)` function needs 2 paramters, a `String` and a [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context).

> And in my button i use
>   `openNewTabWindows("https://Google.com/")`

You just called this function with 1 parameter, then of course

> It say it need context After url.

You need to pass a `Context` as the second parameter. Since you say you are implementing the action of clicking a button (which is, inside `@Override public void onClick(View v) {}` in Java, or a Lambda with type `(View) -> Unit` in Kotlin), which is probably inside an `Activity`, and the reference of `this` may be changed, you can pass `getContext()` or for example `MainActivity.this` as the context needed for program, or

```
openNewTabWindows("https://Google.com/", context) // Kotlin version of getContext()
openNewTabWindows("https://Google.com/", this@MainActivity) // Kotlin version of MainActivity.this
```

May both OK.

Comment: Both not work, at openNewTabWindow("https://example.de/", this@MainActivity) it means unresolved reference @MainActivity

Comment: @KTownMods Change `MainActivity` to your ACTUAL activity name.

Comment: @KTownMods Wait, what is your context? Please provide more code context.